# Does your EC2 instance needs an internet connection to upload logs in Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just a quick question, Does your EC2 instance needs an internet connection to upload logs in Cloudwatch? I read the AWS FAQ about Cloudwatch but It doesn't say anything about internet connection.

Comment: I assume you mean: "does the instance need access either to a IGW or a Nat?".  Why not try it and see?  ISTR it works without a IGW or Nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. CloudWatch (and CloudWatch Logs) have APIs on the public Internet.

Therefore, you would need access to the Internet via an Internet Gateway, NAT or connection through your own data center.

(Only Amazon S3 has the concept of an Endpoint within a VPC, which can therefore bypass a connection to the public Internet.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to simulate it and It is trying to connect to Cloudwatch Logs endpoint to publish stream so it needs an internet.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need an access to Internet. You can use "Endpoints". Just create a new one with link to "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.logs" (for us-east-1). Don't forget to define "Security Groups" of the created endpoint.